# MySQL Left join get double result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with my query. First of all This is my Databases Structures

```
database mt
- mtnobuk
- mtbrg
- mtcolor
- mtloc

database mv
- mvnobuk
- mvrng
- mvmsn
- mtnobuk (FK)
```

And this is my data-

```
MT
mtnobuk     mtbrg   mtcolor     mtloc
---------------------------------------------
MT-112      Shape    Blue       L1

MV
mvnobuk     mvrng   mvmsn       mtnobuk
-------------------------------------------------
MV-111      round   sharp       MT-112
MV-112      oval    blunt       MT-112
```

All I want is I want to query my data like this-

```
mtnobuk     mtbrg       mtcolor       mvrng         mvmsn
----------------------------------------------------------
MT-112      Shape        Blue         round         sharp
                                      oval          blunt
----------------------------------------------------------
```

And this I have tried so far

```
SELECT  mtnobuk,mtbrg,mtcolor,mtloc,mvnobuk,mvrng,mvmsn,mtnobuk
FROM    mv
LEFT JOIN mt on mtnobuk = mvnobuk
WHERE mtnobuk = MT-112
GROUP BY mtnobuk,mtbrg
```

I have tried many times, and all I got is double result, like this

```
mtnobuk     mtbrg       mtcolor       mvrng         mvmsn
----------------------------------------------------------
MT-112      Shape        Blue         round         sharp
                                      oval          blunt
----------------------------------------------------------
MT-112      Shape        Blue         round         sharp
                                      oval          blunt
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I hope someone can help me to solve this thing, thank you guys and have a nice day.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You’re confusing issues of data storage and retrieval with those of data display; the latter being best handled in application code

Answer (score 2):

I think a GROUP CONCAT might be the best you can do. Try it like this:

```
SELECT  mtnobuk, mtbrg, mtcolor, mvnobuk, GROUP_CONCAT(mvrng), GROUP_CONCAT(mvmsn)
FROM    mv
LEFT JOIN mt on mtnobuk = mvnobuk
WHERE mtnobuk = MT-112
GROUP BY mtnobuk, mtbrg, mtcolor, mvnobuk
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 SELECT  mt.mtnobuk, mt.mtbrg, mt.mtcolor, mv.mvnobuk, GROUP_CONCAT(mv.mvrng) as mvrng , GROUP_CONCAT(mv.mvmsn) as mvmsn
FROM    mv
LEFT JOIN mt on mt.mtnobuk = mv.mtnobuk
WHERE mt.mtnobuk = "MT-112"
GROUP BY mt.mtnobuk
```

Comment: with the use table(alias) name with field eg. mt.mtnobuk

Comment: it doesn't work sir, i think the problem is "group by"

Comment: @Rei mtnobuk is primary key ?

Comment: @Rei i edited the query check and let me know if working or not working

Comment: @Rei maybe your left join is not correct .That's the reason result not properly display.

Comment: yes it worked but, it is separate with coma, is there any option to separate it like example that i have given in above?

Comment: @Rei First refer the link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp for what is left join.

Comment: @Rei  If you want to change separation style  use SEPARATOR '  ' under GROUP_CONCAT e.g SELECT  mt.mtnobuk, mt.mtbrg, mt.mtcolor, mv.mvnobuk, GROUP_CONCAT(mv.mvrng SEPARATOR '   ') as mvrng , GROUP_CONCAT(mv.mvmsn SEPARATOR '  ') as mvmsn
FROM    mv
LEFT JOIN mt on mt.mtnobuk = mv.mtnobuk
WHERE mt.mtnobuk = "MT-112"
GROUP BY mt.mtnobuk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158153/discussion-between-ashish-detroja-and-rei).